# Can't upload the zipfile of shapefiles on ArcGIS Online

Tags: shapefile, arcgis-online

I can't upload a zipfile of shapefiles on ArcGIS Online; instead it shows a "This file type is not supported" notification.

Providing the screenshot. [image]

Comment: The UI states "Supported files types are CSV, GeoJSON, KML". Dropping a shapefile zip where it isn't supported is likely to generate that error.

Answer (score 1):

You are most likely using a [public account](https://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/get-started/create-account.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_D91DD2A709AE4FB68A9CC095F1688E05) which is not authorized to create services. An ArcGIS Online user that can create services has an add layer box which looks like the below. Note the inclusion of *Microsoft Excel*, *service definition*, *file geodatabase*, and *shapefile* The simple csv, geojson and kml types only generate feature collections (not a true service)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply . I kept on trying with other options in my setting options .
My setting>General>Primary map viewer>Map Viewer Classic.
It worked for me.

[image]